# Connection nodejs and mongo with docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

This is my docker-compose-file:

```
version: "2"
services:
  rest-api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3007:3007"
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - /data/mongodb/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:latest

RUN rm -rf /tmp/node_modules
ADD package.json /tmp/package.json
RUN cd /tmp && npm install
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /opt/app/

WORKDIR /opt/app
ADD . /opt/app

EXPOSE 3007

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

When I run the image, node is not able to connect to mongo:

```
MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
```

What can be wrong? How can I debug this?

**Update:**

In my node app I have:

```
let connection = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myapp');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Node is trying to connect to Mongo on `localhost`, which fails because it is not running in the same container as Node. Instead, it runs in a different container, i.e. on a different host.

You probably have a line like this in your application:

```
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';
```

It defines where the MongoDB is located. You need to change `localhost` to the actual host, which in your case would be `mongo`.

Answer (score 2):

In your node app you need to reference your container instead of localhost.

In your connection string to mongo use the name `mongo` as the host you are probably just using the default at the minute

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

e.g.

```
mongodb://mongo:27017/
```

You need to do this because the mongo database is in a separate container (with a different IP address) they are linked via TCP so localhost relates to the container node is in.

Comment: @pissall have you got a repo I can look at. Happy to help